# How to update the column based on criteria in TSQL?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following columns:

```
Cost | Rate1 | Rate2 | Rate3 | IsContainRate
100; 95; 100; 105; Y
105; 100; 110; 120; N
95; 95; 100; 130; Y
```

Basically, I want to update the IsContainRate column based on

```
IF (Cost = Rate1 OR Cost = Rate2 OR Cost=Rate3) THEN 
update IsContainRate=Y 
ELSE IsContainRate = N
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TSQL, you can use a `CASE` statement to perform your conditional update.

Here's an example:

```
UPDATE yourTable 
    SET isContainRate = CASE 
                           WHEN (Cost = Rate1 
                                  OR Cost = Rate2 
                                  OR Cost = Rate3) 
                              THEN 'Y' 
                           ELSE
                                'N'
                        END
```

The Case Statement will evaluate out to either 'Y' or 'N' depending on your expression.